# Is it possible to access http content on https site?

Tags: security, https

I have hosted my site on HTTPS server and I am using third party API which is in HTTP.

I think, using HTTP content inside HTTPS site making issues and giving errors like below :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://actionmap.prospectmapping.se/Plans/plan-details?planId=a48a49b0-a64b-4eda-9215-a02b6645c743' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Can anyone suggest what to do if I want to access HTTP API in HTTPS site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixed content may be prevented by either CSP header (Content Security Policy) or by the browser itself (which I believe should be the case in XXI century). Have fun and play with https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/simple-example.html a bit in different browsers.

If the user agent itself disallows mixed content, you can't do anything. Blocking mixed content is meant to protect the end user.

Feel free to read through https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content to learn more.